# How to Retrieve BTC without syncing wallet

Tags: synchronization, wallet-recovery

I bought approximately 1 BTC is 2013. I deposited this BTC with a wallet, but I did not keep the wallet in sync. I recently opened the wallet and it says I have 0.0 BTC, and that I have approximately 60+ weeks of syncing in order to bring my wallet up to speed. My question are as follow:

1.) how can I verify that I still own this BTC?
2.) How can I transfer the BTC to a new wallet without syncing my current wallet?

I am a noob  to BTC, any help would be super appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may want to enter your address into one of the many blockchain "services" webpages, for example: https://blockchain.info/

On the top right you can enter an address, and see if you have a balanceon your address...

Answer (score 1):

You may check the balance in any website that hosts a full node and provide a web service for blockchain viewing, known as "block explorers". pebwindkraft's answer gave you an example.

Regarding waiting for the blockchain to download, you don't have to. You can use light wallets such as [electrum](https://electrum.org). It's safe, secure, is listed in the bitcoin official website and it does not download a local copy of the blockchain. Also, you may even import your existing wallet.